Можно ли написать запрос с IF короче?
if input_user_level == 1:
    user_level = words_easy

elif input_user_level == 2:
    user_level = words_medium

elif input_user_level == 3:
    user_level = words_hard


Можно, а в чём проблема?)

Вариант со словарем - преимущество в возможности получить значение по умолчанию, если введенное значение не соответствует ни одному из ключей:
level_dict = {1: words_easy, 2: words_medium, 3: words_hard}
user_level = level_dict.get(input_user_level, words_medium)

Однострочный формат:
user_level = {1: words_easy, 2: words_medium, 3: words_hard}.get(input_user_level, words_medium)

Вариант со списком от @CrazyElf - преимущество в более коротком описании коллекции (при условии предварительной валидации введенного значения, иначе может возникнуть ошибка IndexError: list index out of range):
level_list = [words_easy, words_medium, words_hard]
user_level = level_list[input_user_level - 1]

Однострочный формат:
user_level = [words_easy, words_medium, words_hard][input_user_level - 1]

Способ, появившийся в версии Python 3.10, оператор match-case - преимущество в возможности далее писать разный код в ветках алгоритма:
match input_user_level:
    case 1:
        user_level = words_easy
        # код 1
    case 2:
        user_level = words_medium
        # код 2
    case 3:
        user_level = words_hard
        # код 3
    case _:  # Иное значение
        user_level = words_easy
        # код 4

Иные способы ранее описывались в данном обсуждении.

Только у него не строки в вопросе.

Точно! Спасибо - исправил ближе к вопросу автора

Тут можно и список как вариант - проверяемые значения ведь числовые и идут подряд.

Совсем упустил, что @extract спрашивает вариант короче - и словарь, и список спокойно переделываются в однострочники

Если на то пошло, то в исходном вопросе не было input(), там была готовая переменная input_user_level, откуда взялось в ней значение вы сами додумали )  Вариант со списком на самом деле может быть плох, если возможны входные значения не укладывающиеся в проверяемый диапазон. Но это нужно уточнять постановку задачи. У словаря с обработкой такого варианта лучше дела обстоят, там можно использовать .get и получить дефолтное значение.

Вы прямо работаете над ответом, реально его улучшаете. Похвально. Даже жалко будет, если вопрос в итоге закроют, как дубликат, ибо наверняка на такие простые вопросы уже были тут ответы. Но вы продолжайте в том же духе, это хорошо, это правильно.
